# Bignum divisibility algorithm

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I need to test whether an integer $b$ divides another integer $a$. Both integers are “bignums”, in the cryptography range ($10^2$ to $10^4$ bits). The integers are represented in binary. Assume that the integers are positive.

Obviously, the faster the better. I'm primarily interested in fast performance when $a$ turns out to be divisible by $b$, so tricks that quickly detect certain cases of non-divisibility are not particularly useful.

I currently have code that calculates the quotient and remainder $(q,r)$ such that $a = b\,q+r$, then tests whether $r = 0$. That's obviously correct, but I'm wondering if I'm performing extra work by calculating and discarding the quotient and the exact value of the remainder.

Is there a more direct way (faster, not using more memory) to test divisibility than to perform the complete integer division?

Comment: You could look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_reduction

Comment: @D.W. If I understand correctly, instead of dividing by $b$, I would calculate $c = \lfloor 2^k / b \rfloor$ and multiply by $c$. Is $\lfloor 2^k / b \rfloor$ easier to calculate than an exact quotient by $b$?

Comment: @Gilles: This is mostly useful when you calculate a mod b for many different values of a, and for a single value of b.

Comment: @D.W.: I didn't know the name "Barrett reduction", but in the end it is just a faster method to calculate q = floor (a / b). To test divisibility, you don't need to calculate q correctly for _all_ values a, but only for multiples of b. That lets you get away with a bit less precision, making the calculation of q a little bit faster. You also don't need to calculate a - q*b and compare it to zero, but just calculate q*b and compare it to a, which may be a bit faster. And you don't need to calculate all bits of q*b, since you know that the highest bits will match.